# XMPP Get All Roster's Presence and Status Messages

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I would like to get all of my contacts presence and status information which they supplied to server before going offline.
I found the below method to query one contact's presence information but what I want to do here is to query all of my contact's presence information at once. Because If I have 200 roster item,  I dont want to make 200 requests.
Is there any way to do something like this
Or is there anyway to change this in the xmpp server(ejabberd) side

Thanks
tolga

Answer (score 1):

Use Roster to get roster status & presence.
Here is an example,

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(this.connection);
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
    @Override
    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {
        // Notified on roster added
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {
        // Notified on roster updated
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {
        // Notified on roster deleted
    }

    @Override
    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
        // Notified in roster status changed
        // You will get presences here
    }
});
```